I'm using the .sum() function to sum rows from a pandas DataFrame and I'm getting the index and dtype
First let me start by saying that I'm pretty new to pandas, so there might be a very easy solution that I'm missing. I have a DataFrame with 61 columns, the first column is the subject and the next 60 columns correspond to 60 trials. Each column has a value of time for each trial.
Here's an example of my data (a shorter version with only 4 columns):
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2, 2], [3, 1, 3, 3], [4, 1, 4, 4], [5, 1, 5, 5]], columns = ['Subject', 'trial1', 'trial2', 'trial3'])
subjects = ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

I want to get the sum of the time up to x trial for all rows and all trials and I'm using the following code:
MyColumns = ['time', 'subject', 'trial']
sum_of_times = pd.DataFrame(columns=MyColumns)
for subject in subjects:
  for trial in range(1, 3):
    MyRow = df.loc[df['Subject'] == subject].index
    time = df.iloc[MyRow, 1:(trial+1)].sum(axis=1)
    new_row = [time, subject, trial]
    sum_of_times.loc[len(sum_of_times)] = new_row
    sum_of_times = sum_of_times.reset_index(drop=True)

sum_of_times

So, for example if I were to go up to trial 2 I would expect to get:
 time  subject  trial
0  1     1        1
1  2     1        2
2  1     2        1
3  3     2        2
4  1     3        1
5  4     3        2
6  1     4        1
7  5     4        2
8  1     5        1
9  6     5        2

Where:

for subject_1 trial_1, I get 1 = 1
for subject_1 trial_2, 1 + 1 = 2
for subject_2 trial_1, 1 = 1
for subject_2 trial_2, 1 + 2 = 3

etc. (I added the _ here so that it is easier to read).
The issue that I'm having is that I'm getting the right numeric values in time but I'm also getting the row index from my original DataFrame (df) and the dtype. This is the output (which i can't find a way to copy and paste properly):
        time       subject  trial
0   0 1 dtype: int64    1   1
1   0 2 dtype: int64    1   2
2   1 1 dtype: int64    2   1
3   1 3 dtype: int64    2   2
4   2 1 dtype: int64    3   1
5   2 4 dtype: int64    3   2
6   3 1 dtype: int64    4   1
7   3 5 dtype: int64    4   2
8   4 1 dtype: int64    5   1
9   4 6 dtype: int64    5   2

Is there a way that I can select only the numeric value?

Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Beside the point, but creating an empty DataFrame and then filling it is an anti-pattern. You can use a list instead then create the new df all at once. I mean, DataFrame.append() was removed on purpose.

Assuming there are no duplicate Subjects
The problem is that time is a Series. You could .squeeze() it into a scalar.

However, the operation you're doing is a cumulative sum, and there are much easier ways to do that if you just clean your data first. I'll use wide_to_long() to change the trial{n} columns into one column of trial numbers and one column of times:
long = (
    pd.wide_to_long(df, "trial", i="Subject", j="_trial")
    .rename(columns={"trial": "time"})
    .rename_axis(index={"_trial": "trial"})
    .sort_index()
)

               time
Subject trial      
1       1         1
        2         1
        3         1
...             ...
5       1         1
        2         5
        3         5

[15 rows x 1 columns]

Then all you need to do is groupby Subject and .cumsum().
result = long.groupby(level="Subject").cumsum()

You said you want the sum "for all trials", so this is the full result. You can select chunks if you want with multi-index slicing, e.g. the first two trials:
result.loc(axis=0)[:, 1:2]

or
idx = pd.IndexSlice
result.loc[idx[:, 1:2], :]

               time
Subject trial      
1       1         1
        2         2
2       1         1
        2         3
3       1         1
        2         4
4       1         1
        2         5
5       1         1
        2         6

And you can .unstack() to view the result as a dense table, similar to the input.
result.unstack('trial')

        time       
trial      1  2   3
Subject            
1          1  2   3
2          1  3   5
3          1  4   7
4          1  5   9
5          1  6  11


Using .squeeze() worked. I didn't try the other method because my actual dataset has a lot more columns and parameters than just subject and trial.

@Cam You could probably select a subset to be able to use the other method. I mean, the process is practically the same as what you posted, just unpivoted.
